# svg cannot be displayed on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, firefox

I have an svg image written using xml code. This code can be opened normally in edge and chrome browsers and displays the content drawn by the svg. However, when I open it with firefox, the page is blank. What is the reason? What's causing it, and how to fix it so that it can display normally on Firefox.

firefox version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRozW.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

  viewBox="112432687.8498 -17346731.0242  120037.6874 57319.0791" version="1.1" overflow="visible" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <g id="draft" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" stroke-width="22.1696">

    <g id="COLUMN" color="rgb(128,128,128)" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="22.1696">

      <g id="ID_52FB" fill="currentColor">

        <path

          d=" M 112460613.0866 17325627.2947 L 112460613.0866 17325827.2947   L 112457813.0866 17325827.2947   L 112457813.0866 17321577.2947   L 112458013.0866 17321577.2947   L 112458013.0866 17325627.2947   L 112460613.0866 17325627.2947 " />

      </g>

    </g>

    

  </g>

</svg>
```

edge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc0b4.png)

firefox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gjP7.png)

Comment: divide the path and viewBox values by 100000

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more straightforward version of your SVG. I scaled the path and moved it to 0,0.

```css
body {
  color: orange;
}

svg {
  border: thin solid gray;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <path d="M 28 40 L 28 42 L 0 42 L 0 0 L 2 0 L 2 40 L 28 40 Z" fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>
```